# yahoo CSV Historical Quotes PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

Trying to use CURL to download yahoo historical quotes but can't get it to connect at all

http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvHistQuotesDownload

Here's an example of `$url` I'm sending

http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DDD&a=11&b=4&c=2013&d=11&e=6&f=2013

```
public function curl($url)
{

  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '25');
  $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));

  if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        print_r($info);
    }

  curl_close($ch);



  return $content;  



}
```

The returned curl info doesn't tell me anything, anybody know how I can get a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: If I try to grab from that URL using curl from the command-line, I get "Failed connect to ichart.yahoo.com:80; Connection refused". So I'd guess that's fundamentally why nothing's coming back.

Comment: Also: What do you see if you check `curl_error($ch)` rather than `curl_getinfo($ch)` in the event of an error? (example [here](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php))

Comment: Adding to what Matt said, I'm unable to resolve the URL at all - Can you? If not, start there.

Comment: Also: is that an official API endpoint? I don't see Yahoo! advertising it anywhere on their developer site, and the information in that third-party wiki article you're pointing at is more than two and a half years old. You might be better off looking for more obviously officially-supported source of historical stock data.

Comment: the curl_errno gives me 7 and then I can look that up but unable to connect not very helpful yahoo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo has changed subdomain name of historical quotes url from

**ichart.yahoo.com**

to

**ichart.finance.yahoo.com**

Try this url
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DDD&a=11&b=4&c=2013&d=11&e=6&f=2013

It works for me.

I found it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/111141-unable-to-return-data-for-given-security-and-date-when-using-fetch-with-yahoo)

Comment: Ah Ok I only set it up a few days ago and it was working then - it doesn't directly answer the question but does solve the problem. Thanks